# Swagger - conflicting method/path combination

Tags: c#, swagger

I'm in the process of adding swagger to my application. In the main controller base there are methods such as get and delete which could look like so:

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}", Order = 1)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
        {
            try
....
```

And then in a specific controller, you can overwrite it by creating a delete method like so:

```
  [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteLibrary(Guid id)
        {
            try
            {
....
```

Now in terms of the application it all works fine, but with Swagger I am getting errors like:

```
SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "DELETE api/Libraries/{id}"
```

I can fix this by updating the configureServices method in my startup file like so:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(apidescriptions => apidescriptions.First());
        });
```

This seems to solve the issue but I am just wondering if this is the best way to go about it  or if there is something else I could add to the deleteLibrary method that would mean it's not conflicting to swagger?

Comment: There are many ways to avoid the error. For example you could add action name to the path. Or it's possible to override method instead of creation a new one.

Comment: Is there a preferred method or is it dealer's choice really? I've just noticed if I update the method to be protected instead of public, that solves the issue as well

Comment: You say it works in your app but how do you reach the second /id route (DeleteLibary)? For me Swagger is correct as its unreachable but maybe there is something i don't know. Presumably got it. Swagger doesn't know about "Order" (rather Swashbuckle or whatever you use).

Comment: well it works as in the swagger UI now shows. When the methods are protected instead the UI will show. Whether the calls actually work I can't say for certain yet due to having to sort authorization for it as I get a 401 error when trying to do the calls within Swagger. Do you have a suggestion for best way to resolve the confliction @Ralf?

Comment: Your intention here is to superseed the endpoint with the Order Parameter correct if and implementor wants that and uses Order correct? Then i assume you need to implement a IDocumentFilter for Swashbuckle to check the endpoint descriptions yourself. I wouldn't trust your current workaround. I doubt apidescriptions are ordered the way you need it but rather in the order swashbuckles find them when scanning the controllers. So its unclear what apidescription is the right one.

Comment: Looking at the source there is a wild solution in using the ResolveConflictingActions action as you try now but via ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes you could get the instance of the HttpMethodAttribute and check the Order attribute explicitly and take the proper one.

Comment: And yes Swashbuckle (now having seen the source) does not know anything about the HttpMethodAttribute beyond Route and Http Verb. So you need todo it yourself.